# How do I convert a number from bytes to GB and round to 2 decimal places?

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I need a script that converts a number from bytes to GB (not GiB) and rounds the result to 2 decimal places. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

```
$ n=1832985293598283    
$ echo  $(echo "scale=2; $n/1000000000"  | bc -l)
1832985.29
$
```

Tells bc to calculate $n divided by a billion, with two decimals. bc should be available almost everywhere.

Comment: But how would I pass an output of a script to this?

Comment: By substituting $n with the output value of the script. For instance by storing the output of the script in a variable.